# What does the asterisk / star (*) at the end of a cargo tree output represent?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

What does the asterisk / star (`*`) at the end of a cargo tree output represent? How and where is it used?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

From https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-tree.html#description:

> Packages marked with (*) have been "de-duplicated". The dependencies for the package have already been shown elsewhere in the graph, and so are not repeated. Use the --no-dedupe option to repeat the duplicates.

Comment: Can I assume that the de-dup is done because the pruned depends have the the same versions?

Comment: A simple check shows you can.